# Comparing two mortage rates.

Tags: finance, actuarial-science

Say I buy a house and take a loan for amount, $a$. The monthly interest rate the bank charges me is $r$ (banks generally quote yearly rates; divide those by $12$ to get $r$), compounded monthly and there are $t$ months in the loan. Every month, I put in extra payments in the amount of $e$.

It is easy to show that at the end of month $\tau$, the total principal paid, $P_{\tau}$ will be given by equation (2) and the total interest paid, $Q_{\tau}$ will be given by equation (3) (I confirmed these on my mortgage). Also, the principal paid in month $\tau$ will be given by equation (1) and so on.

Now, let's say I'm comparing two loans with everything being the same, but the interest rates. The rate of the first loan is $r_1$ and that of the second loan is $r_2 (<r_1)$. I want to know how much money I'll save at the end of period $\tau$ by switching from the first loan to the second. This can be estimated one of two ways.

1. Set the extra payments, $e_1$ of the first loan to $0$ and those of the second loan, $e_2$ such that the total monthly payments for the two become the same. Now, use equation (2) to get the cumulative principal for the two loans and take the difference. Since the monthly payments are the same, the only thing that matters is how much principal we've paid off by the end of $\tau$.
2. Set $e_1=e_2=0$ and take the difference of the cumulative interests (each given by equation (3)) and the difference of the cumulative principals (each given by equation (2)). The difference in total interest paid up to that point and total principals should be the money saved by switching to loan-2.

Of these, I trust the first approach more. The second one doesn't give the same result as the first. What am I missing?

And even in the first approach, the cumulative interest rates are different at the end of $\tau$. What is the significance of this difference?

---

$$p_{\tau} = \left(\frac{ar}{(1+r)^{t}-1} + e\right)(1+r)^\tau \tag{1}$$

$$P_{\tau} = \left(\frac{ar}{(1+r)^{t}-1} + e\right)\left(\frac{(1+r)^\tau-1}{r}\right) \tag{2}$$

$$Q_{\tau} = \tau\left(\frac{ar}{1-(1+r)^{-t}}+e\right)-P_{\tau}\tag{3}$$

---

EDIT: Note that if you want to compare two loans after they've both ended, it's obvious that you simply subtract the total interest paid for the two of them. My question involves ending them prematurely at a time $\tau$ when neither of them has concluded (or one of them has and the other hasn't).

Further, we can ignore the time value of money.

Finally, to make things simple, let's consider only scenario-1. To compare the money saved, one argument would be to take the difference in total principals paid and also the total interests paid by time $\tau$. Another argument would be to just take the difference in cumulative principals since that's the money that actually changes hands between you and the bank and everything else is the same by design. Which of the arguments is correct? If its the second one, what is the significance of the delta in cumulative interests paid?

Comment: In both approaches you will save money because you switch to a loan with smaller interest and therefore higher principal repaid each month. In 1. your second loan has not only lower interest but also an extra payment $e_2$ that drives the outsanding princpal to zero even faster. In 2. that happens slower because $e_2=0\,.$ It is pretty clear to me that in approach 1. you save more money because that second loan lives shorter and you pay less interest than in approach 2.

Comment: Let's go only with the first approach for now. In terms of total transaction, we've been paying equal amounts with the two loans every month and so, only the principal delta in the end should matter. But on the other hand, the cumulative interest paid between the two loans is also different. How should I interpret this delta? What is its significance if it doesn't matter in terms of money saved?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to figure out how to save money when repaying a loan just apply the following simple principles

- The borrowed amount has to be repaid in full. There is no way to save money on that.
- Money can be saved only on the total interest paid by bringing down the outstanding pricipal faster, either by making an extra payment and/or by switching into a loan with less interest and not lowering the monthly fixed payment too much.

You don't even need those complicated formulas to do any calculations. A simple loop in a python program is enough:

```
T = 10 # number of periods
A = 100 # outstanding principal
F = 10 # fixed payment
E = 0 # extra payment
r = 0.01 # interest
Rtot = 0 # total interest paid
for t in range(T):
    R = A*r # interest in period t
    P = F+E-R # repayment on principal
    A -= min(P,A) # outstanding principal
    Rtot += R
    if A < 1e-5:
       break
print( Rtot )
```

Comment: This is fine if you're comparing loans once you pay them both off in full. What if you want to compare them at some point where neither has been paid off. Then, should you subtract the principals and the cumulative interests to get total overall savings?

Comment: @RohitPandey : I was reading your edit of the question. To incorporate the time value of money in a decision whether in the middle of the loan it is better to switch to loan2 or carry on with loan1 the problem becomes indeed a bit more complicated. Please try the following: assume that we put some money $B$ initially into a savings account that earns us the daily rate $\rho$. The time value of $B$ at $t$ is then $Be^{\rho t}$. All cashflows you pay to the debitor reduce the funds in that savings account. Then see how much you have left in the end when you switch and when you didn't switch.

Comment: Should be easy to put into that python code. And also : when $\rho$ is zero both my methods should agree.

Comment: I want to ignore time value of money for now. My question isn't about how to mechanically perform the calculations. Either your Python code or my formulas will work fine there. This is more around interpreting the numbers. In scenario-1 outline in the question, one way of looking at it is to subtract the total principal due for the 2 options. Another is to also add in diff in cumulative interest paid. Should we include the delta in cumulative interest? Why or why not?

Comment: @RohitPandey . OK let's ignore time value of money, but sorry, I don't get it .  Your loan has an amount $A$ that you have to pay back no matter how. It doesn't make sense to compare cumulative principals at any point in time when we ignore time value of money.

Comment: When both loans end, your statement makes sense. But in scenario 1 I described; your monthly payment is exactly the same. So when you end both loans prematurely, what is the difference at the end of the day? The only difference is that you have to pay back less money to the bank in the second loan. Hence, in terms of net cash flow, the money saved with the second strategy should purely be the higher amount of principal you've managed to repay.

Comment: If I was the bank and you wanted to end the loan prematurely I would still ask you to pay back the rest of $A$ to me. You cannot save that money unless you declare bankruptcy.

Comment: yes of course. But some of the $A$ has been paid in the duration that I had the loan. If $P$ is the amount paid in the duration I had the loan, I'll pay the bank $A-P$. First loan, its $A-P_1$ and second loan its $A-P_2$. So the difference in net cash flow between the two is $P_2-P_1$.

Comment: In both loans, I was paying the exact same amount each month (by design of scenario 1). So, the only difference is that I had paid down a larger $P$ by the time I ended the loan for the second one. No other difference in cash flow.